# postgresql join table on same table untill there is no more data to return

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, recursive-query

I am writing a function in pgsql. I have a table A with column child_of_a.
Using this query I can get one child, but I need all of them and I don't know how many of them are in the database.
This returns only one row:

```
SELECT * FROM A a 
INNER JOIN A a2 
ON a2.id=a.child_of_a
```

This returns two rows:

```
SELECT * FROM A a 
INNER JOIN A a2 
ON a2.id=a.child_of_a
INNER JOIN A a3 
ON a3.id=a2.child_of_a
```

Is there a way to solve this problem in postgres, without joining 100 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a recursive query:

```
with tree as (
  select *
  from a 
  where id = ... --- this is your starting point

  union all 

  select c.*
  from a as c
    join tree as p on c.child_of_a = p.id
) 
select * 
from tree;
```

For more details see the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html